# Java: How many Objects created? Array as member variable

Tags: java, arrays, object, garbage-collection

I got a question about the following piece of code.

```
class MemArr{
  int[] mem = {1,2};
}

public class Test{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    MemArr[] x = new MemArr[2];  //line 1  
    x[0] = new MemArr();         //line 2
    x[1] = null;                 //line 3  
                                 //line 4
  }
}
```

How many objects are created in total and how many objects are eligible for garbage collection when line 1 is reached?

I think, that at line 1, there were 5 objects created (1 array x, 2 objects of `MemArr` in the array x, 2 member variables of integer array for the objects of MemArr)

At line 2, two objects were created (one `MemArr` object and its member variable `mem`).

At line 3 when `x[1]` is set to null, I think that there were in total 4 objects which are eligible for the GC, but I am not very sure about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
MemArr[] x = new MemArr[2];
```

This creates a new `MemArr` array of 2 elements but it doesn't initialize any of the 2 elements. After that declaration, `x[0]` and `x[1]` are both `null`: the array was instantiated but not its content.

```
x[0] = new MemArr();
```

This really assigns a new `MemArr` to the first element of the array. So it creates one `MemArr` and another array for the internal `int[] mem` that it contains.

```
x[1] = null;
```

This line doesn't do anything; the value was already `null`, as said before.

Answer (score 1):

The first line creates a single array object of 2 elements. Both elements are null by default, so no `MemArr` objects are created.

The second line creates one `MemArr` object and one internal array object inside that object.

The third line doesn't create any object. In fact, it makes no difference since `x[1]` is already null.